# Google Drive API v3 PHP: Upload a file Call to undefined method

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I've followed the quickstart at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php and everything works fine.

I can search for files, download files but I am not able to upload files.

I'm using this approach here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$result = $service->files->insert($file, array(
   'data' => file_get_contents("path/to/file"),
   'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
   'uploadType' => 'media'
));
```

But I always get an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource::insert()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The **insert** method has changed to **create**:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create

Another pitfall: $file->setTitle does also not work (use setName).

The final code looks like this:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($filename);
$result = $service->files->create($file, array(
  'data' => file_get_contents("path/to/file"),
  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media'
));
```

Comment: What is it ` $service`? How to import this?